# How to configure a new NetworkManager connection from a shell script/command line?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, networkmanager

I've tried to find a way to configure a new connection manageable by NetworkManager using a terminal/shell script all day long, but I've been unsuccessful.

The reason is that I have a lot of openvpn configuration files and I wanted to have a nice and fast way of importing them, also beacuse NetworkManager openvpn plugin doesn't parse the certificates embedded into configuration files, so the only way to configure a new VPN connection is to do that manually via the GUI after I run a script to extract the certificates from the config files, which is a rather long and tedious process.

I found that on RedHat the nmcli utility has the ability to configure a new connection in this way:

```
nmcli con add [...]
```

However this is not possibile on (standard) Linux Mint 17.1.

I tried to add a new connection manually, adding a new file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

```
[connection]
id=VPNConnection
id=3389cf54-949e-4c69-a746-864f0f8720b8
type=vpn

[vpn]
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
fragment-size=1300
connection-type=password-tls
password-flags=1
auth=MD5
tunnel-mtu=1500
cipher=AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo=yes
cert-pass-flags=0
remote=[vpn provider]
port=[vpn port]
mssfix=yes
username=[username]
remote-cert-tls=server
cert=[user cert]
ca=[ca cert]
key=[user priv. key]

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

but this new configuration doesn't show up in NetworkManager.

Also, I don't have any ~/.gconf/system directory, neither under my personal home nor under /root.

Where could NetworkManager read configuration files from?

Comment: [I have the very same issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206468/manual-creation-of-networkmanager-connection-file-fails-error-unknown-connecti) -- have you been able to find a solution in the meantime? Thanks! (I believe that one option is to get the experimental package of NM 1.0 but I don't want to mess with my system that way.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Under `[main]` there should be a `plugins` directive and if you have enabled the `keyfile` plugin (i.e. `plugins=keyfile,ifupdown` or similar), it should monitor the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory for file changes.

Further, a `man NetworkManager.conf` tells you that '*it will ignore files that are readable or writeable by any user or group other than root*'.

Don't know if this solves your problem, but it is worth checking out!

According to [this](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1163023), it should work with NetworkManager v7+

Cheers!
/ Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
nmcli reload "your connection name"
```

followed by a reboot. Reactivation will probably work as well.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. But the `reload` command is not included in my version of NetworkManager (most current package for Raspbian Wheezy). Any other idea? Rebooting and restarting the service [didn't help either](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206468/manual-creation-of-networkmanager-connection-file-fails-error-unknown-connecti).

Comment: I think `nmcli connection reload "your connection name"` is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Running reload command without connection name works just fine - connection name, which is defined by variable `id=` within script itself, can be different than filenane.

```
nmcli connection reload
```

will reload all connections from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

also three things that must be done:

```
chmod 600 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
chown root:root /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

and script itself must be valid :)

To try if it's working fine you may generate with easy script for static IPv4 address and disabled IPv6 with such script:

```
#default first network interface is ens192
interface=ens192
#IPv4
ipv4=10.151.62.83
#mask in one or two-digits format - for local networks 8 to 32
maskv4=24
#ipv4 gateway address
gateway=10.151.62.254
#dns
dns="10.0.0.1;10.0.0.2"
#domain which will be used to search hosts, can be more than one 
domain="example.com;example.net"

echo -e "[connection]\nid=$interface\nuuid=$(uuidgen -t)\ntype=ethernet\nautoconnect-pririty=-999\ninterface-name=$interface\n\n[ethernet]\n\n[ipv4]\naddress1=$ipv4/$maskv4,$gateway\ndns=$dns\ndns-search=$domain;\nmay-fail=false\nmethod=manual\n\n[ipv6]\nignore-auto-dns=true\nignore-auto-routes=true\nmethod=disabled\nnever-default=true\n\n[proxy]" > /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/$interface.nmconnection
```